# Why does 「頭にきた」signify being mad at something?

Tags: etymology, set-phrases

Is there any source or explanation for the phrase「頭にきた」and why it means to be angry?

For example:

> 彼の言ったこととその言い方にはイライラして頭にきた。

Why does "what he said and the way he said it came to my head" mean that I should be annoyed or irritated? Why is 「頭」important and not something else? At first glance, I thought that the phrase was similar to "気づく", but it is not.

Comment: we have "don't let it get to your head" in English.

Comment: @Flaw: Yes that's true. However, that phrase isn't necessarily associated with being "irritated". I thought it was used in the context of someone being prideful and telling them to be more humble.

Comment: There's also "*go* to your head". Hm... I'm not sure of their meanings anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I think of it as blood rushing to my head when I am angry.

Comment: I don't know if it's etymologically accurate, but it makes sense to me.  Compare the similar phrase 頭に血が上る.

Comment: +1: To back this up: `怒りや悲しみや驚きなどのために、頭に血がのぼる` ([reference](http://dic.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?ei=UTF-8&p=%E9%A0%AD%E3%81%AB%E6%9D%A5%E3%82%8B&fr=dic&stype=prefix)).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer your looking for. But maybe if you're looking for an easier way to remember that. We do have a phrase in English kind of like that: "it got to me." If you tried to explain that, you'd run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the body is imagined as a vessel that can contain things, frustration and anger being some of those things, and the theoretical limit is when we're filled up to the head.